# Toggling shopping list item with .done class works with one function, but not the other, why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, dom

```js
var button = document.querySelector("#enter");
var input = document.querySelector("#userInput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var list = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

function inputLength() {
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement() {
          // create a new li child element
          var li = document.createElement("li");  
          // create a text node, simple text, but is not attached to document yet
          li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
          // attach the li variable to its parent ul
          ul.appendChild(li);
          input.value = ""
}

function addListAfterClick(){
    if(inputLength() > 0){
        createListElement();
    }
}

function addListEventKeypress(event) {
    if(inputLength() > 0 && event.keyCode === 13){
        createListElement();
    }
}

//THIS DOES NOT WORK
// function strikeThrough(){
//     this.classList.toggle("done");
// }

// for (var i=0; i<list.length; i++) {
//     list[i].addEventListener('click', strikeThrough);
// }


// THIS WORKS
function strikeThrough(event) {
    if (event.target.tagName === "LI") {
        event.target.classList.toggle("done");
    }
}

ul.addEventListener("click", strikeThrough);

//

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);

input.addEventListener("keypress", addListEventKeypress);
```

```css
.done {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>
    <p id="first">Get it done today</p>

    <input id="userInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter Items">
    <button id="enter">Enter</button>
    
    <ul>
        <li class="bold red" random="23">Notebook</li>
        <li>Jello</li>
        <li>Spinach</li>
        <li>Rice</li>
        <li>Birthday Cake</li>
        <li>Candles</li>
    </ul>
    
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm working on a project where if you click on the list item, it adds a strike through on the element. I typed up a function with the comment `//THIS DOES NOT WORK` and it seemed to work fine, until I created additional list elements, which the `strikeThrough()` function would not work on.

However, after googling around, I found someone elses solution that I tried on my own, which has a comment stating `//THIS WORKS`, which sure enough, works on new elements. Why does this function work, when mine doesn't?

My only guess is the `list.length` in the for loop is fixed at its current length when the file is loaded, am I remotely close here?

Thanks everyone, I'm stumped and need your assistance.

Comment: What is `this` supposed to refer to in that function?

Comment: I still need to familiarize myself with this, but doesn't "this" refer to the list item that is interacted with in the loop right underneath it?

Comment: no, `this` does not interact with anything. `this` means something different, depending on the context you are calling it.

Comment: Sorry missed your response, any idea why `this` works on the initial `li` tags but not new then? I also tried `event.target` on my failed function and it gave me the same results.